# Influence of Samkhya on other darshanas

Tags: philosophy, sankhya, shad-darshana

Can I say Sankhya as the oldest hindu philosophy has influenced all the other darshanas like Vedanta? That implies all astika darshanas are derivative from Sankhya, not necessarily conflicting or contradictory.

Let's get the example Advaita Vedanta vs Samkhya:

Sankhya says there is phenomenical world and the observer of phenomenical world.
Advaita says there is phenomenical world and the observer of phenomenical world, but the observer is the unmanifest and the phenomenical world the manifest of the same principle - Brahman.

So, for me Advaita Vedanta looks like a panentheistic adaptation of Sankhya saying the duality is illusion because both comes from Brahman and only Brahman is real per se.

Seems like Sankhya defines the obvious relationship of human and nature and Vedanta (any school) adds the mystical view on human, nature and Brahman.

Yes, I know sankhya and yoga have close relationship, so I don't want to discuss yoga here.

Comment: Advaita Vedānta is not pantheistic, that's western philosophic misinterpretation. Sāṅkhya school is much older than Advaita Vedānta, there have been scholarly discussions of there being an ancient Sāṅkhya school of which is described a bit even in Mahābhārata but is not the same as what's presented in Sāṅkhyakārikā. Sāṅkhyasūtra is lost. It's hard to say which is the oldest Vedic philosophical school,  Pūrva Mīmāṁsā of Jaimini is pretty old as well. There is lack of proper data, but I would think Mīmāṁsā is older than Sāṅkhya.

Comment: You aren't wrong in saying that Sāṅkhya did influence other systems of thought, but tbh, it's not only Sāṅkhya, many Vedic and non-Vedic systems influenced each other in history. Sāṅkhya was *one of the* oldest Vedic schools, but as for it was the oldest or not? It's hard to be sure about that, because Pūrva Mīmāṁsā seems more to be in line with the Vedic view as it focuses on rituals as in ṛgveda rather than on mokṣa or its elements. Mokṣa wasn't an idea in early Vedic lit. It only started being developed in late Vedic and in Upaniṣadic period.

Comment: So, according to me Sāṅkhya is at the earliest considering its systematic and liberation oriented system probably started to develop in late Vedic or early Upaniṣadic period.